# Nativescript Http Module Error Connection Refused

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I am getting the following error while trying to implement the Nativescript tutorial code found [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3)

`"originalStack": "Error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused\n 
at ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.NotecardRestaurants/
files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:993:33)\n...`

Here is the source for app.module

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app.routing";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { UserService } from './shared/user/user.service';

import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the source for user.service that is causing the issue

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

import { User } from "./user";
import { Config } from "../config";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  register(user: User) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http.post(
      Config.apiUrl + "/user/register",
      JSON.stringify({
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }),
      { headers: headers }
    )
    .map(response => response.json().token)
    .catch(this.handleErrors);
  }
  login(user: User) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http.post(
       Config.apiUrl + "user/login",
      JSON.stringify({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }),
      { headers: headers }
    )
    .map(response => response.json().token)
    .catch(this.handleErrors);
  }

  handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.dir(error.json());
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
}
```

I have independently verified the integrity of the api I am using. The routes given do work. I am running the nativescript project using

`tns run android --emulator`

Comment: Does your api is over `http` or `https`  http is by default blocked until whitelisted

Comment: Definitely `http`

Comment: Whitelist http ;) way to whitelist http check it on net or u can use `Lets Encrypt` for example to get SSL certificate for working https

Comment: Do you mean whitelist in nativescript? The server is on my localhost.

Comment: Check for android/ios whitelisting http requests as i don't remember how now, do you have localhost in `Config.apiUrl`? you need to change it to ip address as localhost points to actual device (mobile) so care about that

Comment: If you try with a device through USB, you should use the real domestic IP address of your computer

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your application on IOS simulator or Android emulator, which is basically virtual machine and if you are referring 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' these are IP of virtual machine not your development machine. you can solve your problem by providing IP of your development machine or in android you can use 10.0.2.2 IP for your development machine. sample of your api url is
https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/news/getnews